# Trouble using Eclipse IDE for C

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt, windows-console

This is my first time with `Eclipse C/C++`. I installed it 2 days ago and still trying to figure it out, by writing `simple C Programs`.

Here are 2 snapshots of the `IDE`:

1. Code Screenshot :

[image]

2. Console Screenshot :

[image]

My questions are :

1. No Command Prompt pop on executing the code. Every output is displayed in its `console view`(If its a feature of the `IDE` that is another thing).
2. When I executed the code in the `screenshot 1`, I was expecting the following:

`First Number :      //this should be displayed & then I enter 5
 Second number :     //after hitting ENTER, I press 6 in this line`

```
Result :         //after hitting ENTER, these 2 lines must be displayed
5 + 6 = 11
```

But on executing the source code, the `console view` of the `IDE` is clean & clear with nothing written on it. I entered the numbers as shown in the `2nd Screenshot`, and than the rest of the string is displayed.

Why is it happening? Am I missing any type of settings or is it the way `Eclipse C/C++` works.

Comment: try flushing the stream after the printf and before the scanf: `fflush(stdout); ` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin

Comment: @bolov Link provided by you was helpful. Thanks. :)